# Export C/C++ switch/case jump table information

Tags: compiler-construction, switch-statement, clang, llvm, jump-table

In C/C++ on x86-64, if a switch/case statement is relatively large (more than 3 or 4 entries), a jump table would be generated by LLVM, instead of conditional jump instructions.

In Clang/LLVM, how to export these tables' base, index, and scale information? Program source code is available.

For example, for
`jmpq   *0x400000(,%rbx,8)`,

How to export the base `0x400000`, the index value which will be compared to the value in `%rbx`, and the scale `8`?

Comment: Why do you need to deal with this manually in Clang/LLVM? It already handles switch/case statement in a similar fashion.

Comment: I mean exporting these information out for other uses, not to change or add functionalities for LLVM.

Comment: you mean this? http://reviews.llvm.org/rL210280

Comment: It seems info can be got from `llvm/CodeGen/MachineJumpTableInfo.h`, right?

Comment: you might need to patch Clang for that. http://reviews.llvm.org/D4128